# Facebook: Reuse credentials from mobile app in browser

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

There are various forms of this question floating around out there - but none of them seem to be exactly what I want to do.

I'm developing for Android.  I have a web-app, NOT a native-app.  On our web-app's page, we have a Login via Facebook button.

Question:  If, on my phone, I'm logged in to Facebook via the Facebook Android app, NOT the mobile Facebook site, is it possible to somehow reuse those credentials in my browser?  I know it's possible to call out to the facebook app using fb:// urls, but it doesn't seem possible to reuse credentials from an app in the browser.

Comment: you got answer for this?

Comment: FYI, I never got an answer for this.  We decided it just wasn't possible.